# Serialize() form in an existing ajax function

Tags: php, ajax, var

Actually the following function works fine, but now I need to add other variable in order to return from the php file the right statement.

```
function sssssss1(page) {
    loading_show();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "load_data.php",
        data: "page=" + page,
        success: function (msg) {
            $("#search").ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
                loading_hide();
                $("#search").html(msg);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I need to add the following two variable to be read by my php file. I have tried different solution, but nothing seem working

```
var form2 = document.myform2;
var dataString1 = $(form2).serialize();
```

How to add those variable in my existing function? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send object as data,

this line:

```
data: "page="+page,
```

could be

```
 data: {mypage:"page="+page, form2:document.myform2, dataString1:$(form2).serialize()}
```

and your PHP can get it like:

```
$page = $_GET['mypage'];
$form2 = $_GET['form2'];
$dataString = $_GET['dataString1'];
```

Hope it Help.

Comment: where "mypage" is load_data.php?

Comment: typo, sorry. Just fixed.